# Database for store images

Tags: mongodb, nosql, blob, datafile, filetable

Actualy I'm using MongoDB with embedded images next to other data in same documents.
Images count actualy are more than 14000 and each image size is less than 1MB. Images are readed frequently and updated rarely.

I want to separate images from data and store it in different database than data to use it as microservice and for scalability. I've read people saying that the best solution to store images is on file system, but you have limitations about number of files in folder and in a lot of CloudComputing services you don't have access to the file system. In MongoDB official documentation, they say that [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#when-to-use-gridfs) is faster than file system, but I've understood that the most case to use GridFS is when you have files with size more than 16MB.

Do you know if there are some specific database to store files?
If not, what conventional database is more efficient to store files?
Is MongoDB a good solution to store files? If yes, what is better for the size of my images, storing as normal documents in collection or as GridFS?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could do it using GridFS.

This is best approach.